# Change viber for windows downdload location from

Tags: windows, viber

Is it possible to change the location of viber download location in windows?! Default is set to `<users>\<current-user>\Documents\ViberDownloads`

For ubuntu I found that it can be done as said in https://askubuntu.com/questions/558599/how-to-change-the-location-of-viber-downloads-folder

For windows I found a sqlite db file and open it, but the default folder not set in there !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a bit late, but I found I way to do this...

1. Close `Viber.exe` (you know, right-click on viber icon in tray and exit :) )
2. Go to the settings folder of viber `c:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\ViberPC\<your_number>\`

**note: This is the folder with the Viber Settings** (there is another one `...\AppData\Local\Viber` - this is Viber's install folder

3. Locate the `viber.db` file
4. Open it with SqLite and open the `Settings` table
5. Change the `DownloadFolder` in the database - like on this picture

   [image]

**note:** For some reason, when you right-click on an image and select `open in folder`, the folder doesn't show up in explorer, but you can left-click on the image (view it) and you can open the folder from your photo viewer.

Comment: There's no more DownloadFolder

Comment: Must be outdated... There's no `ViberPC` under `<user-name>\AppData\Roaming` anymore.

Comment: For future references, please check @hoonose answer creating a symlink. Corrected syntax is in a comment to his answer.

Answer (score 6):

Why not replace the deeply hidden Viber media downloads folder with a symlink.

Move the downloads folder to wherever you want and then link it to the old location.

In Windows (Vista+) that would be

```
mklink /d %userprofile%\ViberDownloads [your_new_path]
```

Works like charm.

Comment: Some mistakes, but still upvoting as it is perfectly valid solution. Valid syntax should in fact be: `mklink /D %userprofile%\ViberDownloads [your_new_path]`

Comment: Just try it with the lowercase switch and see it work. This is not a mistake, this is Windows, sir.

Comment: Just wrote what I tried and observed as an output.  Does it make difference between Win7/Win10? What about PowerShell?

Comment: And yes, your new (moved) folder should come second, while first comes the symlink to be created. Thanks!

Comment: My Win 8.1 folder was in C:\Users\uname\Documents\ViberDownloads  . Moved the folder to D: drive and then made softlink. Worked great.

Answer (score 2):

It used to work this way, but nowdays there is no "DownloadFolder" setting.
Do not help if I add it,
 Viber downloads path is still %Mydocuments%\viberdonload